# Different types of unaligned access in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Linux suggests two types of macros for unaligned access: byteshifts and memmoves.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/include/linux/unaligned

asm-generic which seems to be the most generic implementation of unaligned accesses always includes only byteshifts:

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/include/asm-generic/unaligned.h,

Although my simple benchmarks show that memmove is usually a little more effective.

I also can't find any actual examples of using unaligned memmoves in linux kernel.

Why is that?

Are there any platforms where byteshifts can be more effective than memmoves?

Why is there no implementation which uses memcpy instead of memmove?

Comment: `memcpy` assumes the memory regions you're working with don't overlap. This assumption is often out-right wrong (i.e., when moving data to the top of a buffer) or isn't safe (if you don't control the context in which your function is called)... hence, `memmove` is often preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I'm not the most authoritative source on Linux kernel code. If I were, I would probably argue your assumptions.

As things go:

- "Byteshifts" (i.e., `(a[0] << 8) | a[1]`, depending on byte order) is usually more effective than a function call, since we know the amount of data we wish to copy... which is often the case.

  The inline static functions used by the kernel are optimized away into a few simple instructions, leaving us with the best possible footprint when all we needed was to read 16, 32 or 64 bits.

  I have no idea how you performed your benchmark, but I really doubt `memmove` can beat this approach unless the compiler optimized it away.
- `memcpy` assumes the memory regions you're working with don't overlap.

  This assumption is often out-right wrong, if not merely unsafe.

  For example, we might be moving data within a buffer, which means the data might overlap the writing portion, or we might be writing a function that will be used by many other parts of the kernel and can't really make any assumption about the memory source.

  I would also point out that the extra little bit of math in `memmove` is very cheap.

  No memory dereferencing is involved which means we won't experience cache misses and we're only likely to experience instruction prediction errors (when the CPU predicts the wrong `if` result) if `memcpy` would have been a mistake anyway.